# Why promise.all in below code returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

This is the code snippet where I want to get the URL of all uploaded images in `promise.all` but when I am invoking the `uploadFile` function, it returns an empty array. Can anyone please help me on this issue.

```
export default function uploadFile(fileInfo) {
  const promises = [];

  fileInfo.forEach((item) => {
    const uploadTask = projectStorage
      .ref()
      .child(`${item.path}/${item.imageName}`)
      .put(item.file);
    // promises.push({ task: uploadTask });
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        promises.push(snapshot);
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
      },
      (error) => console.log(error.code),
      async() => {
        promises.push(await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
      }
    );
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

[code snippet of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Hot.png)

Comment: Because the `Promise.all( <array> )` is returned immediately, before the download is completed.

Comment: Thanks bro. So how should I use promise.all in such scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: And please post code as text and not as image ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're populating the `promises` inside the `on` listener, and there is nothing that makes the `return Promise.all(promises)` wait until the `on` calls have completed.

Luckily, calling `put` returns a promise already, which resolves once the upload has completed. So instead of using the `on` callback to signal completion, you can wait for the `put` to resolve:

```
export default function uploadFile(fileInfo) {
  const promises = fileInfo.map((item) => {
    const uploadRef = projectStorage
      .ref()
      .child(`${item.path}/${item.imageName}`)l
    const uploadTask = uploadRef.put(item.file);
    /*
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
      },
      (error) => console.log(error.code),
      async() => { }
    );
    */
    return uploadTask.then(() => return uploadRef.getDownloadURL());
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you go around the `forEach` loop you need to:

- Create a promise
- Add it to the `promises` array

You aren't creating any promises. You're using a regular callback API and are trying to put the final result from the callback into the array (but that happens in the future, which is after you have passed the empty array to `Promise.all`.

See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) for how to wrap `uploadTask.on` in a promise.

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672557/send-request-on-filereader-onload/71704030#71704030) about converting calling a callback API multiple times and gathering all the results together using `Promise.all`.